# Getting response value from jQuery AJAX call before success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a system that making it's AJAX calls through jQuery. I want to take all the received data with the request details, without modifying the current uses of $.ajax, and send it to another API for analysis.

I tried to use $.ajaxSetup for that:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function (request, details) {
    request.success(function (response) {
      analysis.sendData(details, response);
    })
  }
})
```

But the success function from the invocation of $.ajax happened before my success function, and sometimes there are modifications in the response object. 
Apparently in those cases I'm getting the same, modified, response object.

Is there a way to read the response object before the success function?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to make a second request (analysis) - sending the data from the first request? after finishing the first request.. is that right?

Comment: I don't really care when to make the request, I just need to send the original data. But when I do it with ajaxSetup it sends the same object (that sometimes got modified) to all the success functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling the `success` function, you should replace it with a function that performs your extra call, then calls the original success function.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(request, settings) {
        var origSuccess = settings.success;
        settings.success = function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            settings.success = origSuccess;
            analysis.sendData(settings, response, textStatus, jqXHR);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I should be calling request.success, but i didn't noticed the settings.success :)